# Mismatched Input "when" Pyspark but other case when statement works

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I run the following code in a jupyter Pyspark environment:

```
max(case when 
lower(drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay) like '%onpattro%'
or lower(drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay) like '%patisiran%'
or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.314'
and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('d08858'))
or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.312'
and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('287393', '287396', '287397,'287399','308546'))
 or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.69'
and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('71336100001'))
or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.88'
and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('2053490','2053521','2053522','2053523','2053524','2053525','2053526','2053527','2053528','2053529','2053530','2053531','2284712','2284714'))
   or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.96'
and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('37498111000001109','773605008','773608005')) then 1 else 0 end) as on_ind,
```

I get the following error:

```
    Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o42.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input 'when' expecting {')', ','}(line 10, pos 9)



 `== SQL ==

'select
tenant as med_tenant, 
personid as med_personid, 
medicationid as med_medicationid, 
encounterid as med_encounterid,
drugcode.standard.codingSystemId as codingSystemId,
drugcode.standard.id as drugCode,
drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay as drugDesc,
max(case when lower(drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay) like '%onpattro%'
---------^^^
    or lower(drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay) like '%patisiran%'
    or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.314'
    and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('d08858'))
    or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.312'
    and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('287393', '287396', '287397,'287399','308546'))
     or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.69'
    and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('71336100001'))
    or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.88'
    and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('2053490','2053521','2053522','2053523','2053524','2053525','2053526','2053527','2053528','2053529','2053530','2053531','2284712','2284714'))
       or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.96'
    and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('37498111000001109','773605008','773608005')) then 1 else 0 end) as on_ind,
max(case when
    lower(drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay) like '%givlaari%'
    or lower(drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay) like '%givosiran%'
    or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.314'
    and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('d09456')) then 1 else 0 end) as giv_ind
    
    
FROM medication
WHERE
    lower(status.standard.primaryDisplay) not in ('cancelled','canceled','error entry deleted')
    
GROUP BY
    tenant, 
    personid, 
    medicationid, 
    encounterid,
    drugcode.standard.codingSystemId,                                                        
    drugcode.standard.id,
    drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay
    

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ParseException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-8f5dff49e939> in <module>
     39     drugcode.standard.id,
     40     drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay
---> 41     """)

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in sql(self, sqlQuery)
    765         [Row(f1=1, f2=u'row1'), Row(f1=2, f2=u'row2'), Row(f1=3, f2=u'row3')]
    766         """
--> 767         return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
    768 
    769     @since(2.0)

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     71                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     72             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: '):
---> 73                 raise ParseException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     74             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: '):
     75                 raise StreamingQueryException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)

ParseException: "\nmismatched input 'when' expecting {')', ','}(line 10, pos 9)\n\n== SQL ==\n\nselect\ntenant as med_tenant, \npersonid as med_personid, \nmedicationid as med_medicationid, \nencounterid as med_encounterid,\ndrugcode.standard.codingSystemId as codingSystemId,\ndrugcode.standard.id as drugCode,\ndrugcode.standard.primaryDisplay as drugDesc,\nmax(case when lower(drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay) like '%onpattro%'\n---------^^^\n    or lower(drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay) like '%patisiran%'\n    or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.314'\n    and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('d08858'))\n    or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.312'\n    and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('287393', '287396', '287397,'287399','308546'))\n     or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.69'\n    and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('71336100001'))\n    or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.88'\n    and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('2053490','2053521','2053522','2053523','2053524','2053525','2053526','2053527','2053528','2053529','2053530','2053531','2284712','2284714'))\n       or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.96'\n    and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('37498111000001109','773605008','773608005')) then 1 else 0 end) as on_ind,\nmax(case when\n    lower(drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay) like '%givlaari%'\n    or lower(drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay) like '%givosiran%'\n    or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.314'\n    and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('d09456')) then 1 else 0 end) as giv_ind\n    \n    \nFROM medication\nWHERE\n    lower(status.standard.primaryDisplay) not in ('cancelled','canceled','error entry deleted')\n    \nGROUP BY\n    tenant, \n    personid, \n    medicationid, \n    encounterid,\n    drugcode.standard.codingSystemId,                                                        \n ` drugcode.standard.id,\n    drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay\n    \n"'
```

but when I run the block:

```
`max(case when
    lower(drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay) like '%givlaari%'
    or lower(drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay) like '%givosiran%'
    or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.314'
    and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('d09456')) then 1 else 0 end) as giv_ind`
```

That runs. Both statements seem syntactically identical to me, so why is the first throwing an error? I have tried changing the position various elements in the code in multiple ways but have had no success. Even removing the case statement just changes the position of the error to the 'lower' command.

I appreciate any help on this as it is a major blocker for me.
​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in the posted code you are missing one **single** quote `'` at **`'287397'`** try adding single quote and run the query again.

```
max(case when 
lower(drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay) like '%onpattro%'
or lower(drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay) like '%patisiran%'
or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.314'
and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('d08858'))
or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.312'
and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('287393', '287396', '287397','287399','308546'))
 or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.69'
and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('71336100001'))
or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.88'
and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('2053490','2053521','2053522','2053523','2053524','2053525','2053526','2053527','2053528','2053529','2053530','2053531','2284712','2284714'))
   or (drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.96'
and lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('37498111000001109','773605008','773608005')) then 1 else 0 end) as on_ind,
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to format your expression.

```
max(expr('''
    CASE WHEN 
            lower(drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay) like '%onpattro%' or
            lower(drugcode.standard.primaryDisplay) like '%patisiran%' or
            (
                drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.314' and 
                lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('d08858')
            ) or 
            (
                drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.312' and 
                lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('287393', '287396', '287397', '287399', '308546')
            ) or 
            (
                drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.69' and 
                lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('71336100001')
            ) or 
            (
                drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.88' and 
                lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('2053490', '2053521', '2053522', '2053523',' 2053524', '2053525', '2053526', '2053527', '2053528', '2053529', '2053530', '2053531', '2284712', '2284714')
            ) or 
            (
                drugcode.standard.CodingSystemid ='2.16.840.1.113883.6.96' and 
                lower(drugcode.standard.id) in ('37498111000001109', '773605008', '773608005')
            ) 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END) as on_ind
'''))
```